# AHK keyword activation

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

found this on a site
can any one tell me what key  to press to activate the startwork

```
WorkStartup()
{   
    Run, powershell Start Outlook
}

:*:startwork::
    WorkStartup()
return
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at a [Hostring](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotstrings.htm). You need to type the literal word `startwork` anywhere in order for `WorkStartup()` to be ran.

In your example, the `*` option is active, which, according to the link, means:

> - (asterisk): An ending character (e.g. space, period, or enter) is not required to trigger the hotstring.